# Text is not getting printed once the Threads are done

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans, executorservice, blockingqueue

Please have a look at the following code.

```
public class BigFileWholeProcessor {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2;
    public void processFile(String fileName) {

        BlockingQueue<String> fileContent = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        BigFileReader bigFileReader = new BigFileReader(fileName, fileContent);
        BigFileProcessor bigFileProcessor = new BigFileProcessor(fileContent);
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        es.execute(bigFileReader);
        es.execute(bigFileProcessor);
        es.shutdown();

        if(es.isTerminated())
        {
            System.out.println("Completed Work");
        }

    }
}



public class BigFileReader implements Runnable {
    private final String fileName;
    int a = 0;
    public static final String SENTINEL = "SENTINEL";

    private final BlockingQueue<String> linesRead;
    public BigFileReader(String fileName, BlockingQueue<String> linesRead) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.linesRead = linesRead;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //since it is a sample, I avoid the manage of how many lines you have read
            //and that stuff, but it should not be complicated to accomplish
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("E:/Amazon HashFile/Hash.txt")));
            String str = "";

            while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                linesRead.put(str);
                System.out.println(a);
                a++;
            }
            linesRead.put(SENTINEL);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Completed");
    }
}



public class BigFileProcessor implements Runnable {
    private final BlockingQueue<String> linesToProcess;
    public BigFileProcessor (BlockingQueue<String> linesToProcess) {
        this.linesToProcess = linesToProcess;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String line = "";
        try {
            while ( (line = linesToProcess.take()) != null) {
                //do what you want/need to process this line...

                if(line==BigFileReader.SENTINEL)
                {
                    break;
                }
                String [] pieces = line.split("(...)/g");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print the text "completed work" in `BigFileWholeProcessor` once all the thread work is done. But instead, it is not getting printed. Why is this? How to identify that all the threads are done and need printing?

Comment: @Smutje: I do not understand how to map those answers into mine.

Comment: You have an executor service and you want to wait for all executed threads to finish. Just check the first answer.

Comment: @Smutje: I did. I have never worked with this executer thing, I do not understand how to apply that to here. Do you min providing the solution?

Comment: After your `shutdown` paste
try {
  taskExecutor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}

Comment: @Smutje: I guess you should provide it as an answer if you think it will help.

Answer (score 0):

shutdown() only signal ES to shutdown, you need

awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)

before print message

Answer (score 0):

Use `submit()` method instead of `execute()`. The `get()` method can be used if you want to wait for the thread to finish at any point of time. Read documentation on use of `Future` object for further details.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Future<?> f = es.submit(new Thread(new TestRun()));
f.get(); // Wait for result... (i.e similar to `join()` in this case)
es.shutdown(); // Shutdown ExecutorService 
System.out.println("Done.");
```

I have defined a `TestRun` class implementing `Runnable`, not shown here. The `Future` object makes more sense in other scenarios.